# Is there a better way to search for arbitrary text in SQL Server 2008, without CLR or full-text?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008, without using full-text indexing or CLR integration, is there a better way to search a table column for arbitrary text than the following:

```
declare @SubString nvarchar(max) = 'Desired substring may contain any special character such as %^_[]'

select * from Items where Name like '%' +

    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
    replace(
        @SubString
    ,';',';;')
    ,'%',';%')
    ,'[',';[')
    ,']',';]')
    ,'^',';^')
    ,'_',';_')

    + '%' escape ';'
```

That works, but it seems unnecessarily barbaric. Is there any simpler, clearer, or more efficient way, given the above limitations?

There are no constraints on what the `Name` column might contain, nor what the SubString we're searching for might contain.

Comment: Well, instead of using `LIKE` you could use the `CHARINDEX` function.  But that's not any kind of improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to turn your `replace(replace(replace...` into a user-defined function.  Then you could streamline your query into:

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Name LIKE CleanMyString(@Substring) escape ';'
```

It's not exactly "simpler".  It's not likely to be any more efficient.  But it does clean up the syntax and make it cleaner-looking.

Answer (score 0):

(You can use charindex for straight string searches such as finding every firstname that contains Ben  with:

```
 select * for customers where charindex('Ben', firstname) > 0
```

or you can create all kinds of powerful pattern searching with patindex:

```
SELECT PATINDEX ('%[0-9].%[0-9].%[0-9].%','278.2.6.49');
```

which returns the number before the first dot or 0 if there aren't three sets of numbers in the string.

For a very good introduction of using patterns (its not regular expressions) in TSQL (from where the above example was copied) please see:
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/patindex-workbench/